# Event from JAva Script to objective c

Tags: iphone

I am developing a map application for iPhone.I am using google maps API to develop this,by adding the java script file to the resource.My problem is that I need to catch an event defined in the java script. for eg: I need to cath the following event in  java script
"GEvent.addListener(poly, "click", function(latlng, index)" .
Please anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using MapKit?  Is this a web app only?

You can call javascript to probe if something has happened, but you cannot have javascript call back to your code... at least not directly.  You can override the URL handling and have javascript included that tries to make an external call that your code recognizes and acts on.